# Why does `scipy.optimize.minimize(...)` fail with this toy constrained minimisation case?

Tags: constrained-optimization, scipy

I'm learning `scipy.optimize.minimize`.  I thought of a simple function to see how it works:

$$f(x) = x$$

With the goal to minimise $f(x)$, subject to the constraint that:
$$x \ge 0.1$$

Without the constraint, there is no solution (except in the limit $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = \infty$).  But with the constraint $x \ge 0.1$, my logic says that the solution must be also $x=0.1$ since it's the smallest permissible number according to the constraint.

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy
import scipy

def f(x, *args):
    return x[0]

def fc1(x):
    # x[0]       >= 0.1
    # x[0] - 0.1 >= 0
    return x[0] - 0.1

x0 = numpy.array([1])

c1 = {'type':'ineq', 'fun':fc1}

scipy.optimize.minimize(f, x0, [c1])
```

But it results in a failure:

```
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:241: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.sum(np.abs(x)**ord, axis=0)**(1.0 / ord)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:1417: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in scalar multiply
  if (alpha_k*vecnorm(pk) <= xrtol*(xrtol + vecnorm(xk))):
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py:1439: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  Hk = np.dot(A1, np.dot(Hk, A2)) + (rhok * sk[:, np.newaxis] *
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_linesearch.py:276: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  return f(xk + alpha * pk, *args)
Out[4]: 
  message: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
  success: False
   status: 2
      fun: -3.3921181109909714e+155
        x: [-3.392e+155]
      nit: 47
      jac: [ 1.000e+00]
 hess_inv: [[       inf]]
     nfev: 7037
     njev: 3518
```

**Question:** What am I misunderstanding about the concept?  I think I have a fundamental understanding mistake about how this works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the constraint list as a positional argument, but it should be a keyword argument: `scipy.optimize.minimize(f, x0, constraints=[c1])`.

As you have written it `[c1]` is assumed to be `args` and thus is passed to your objective funciton`f`, but `f` doesn't do anything with `args[0]`. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions

Answer (score 1):

do not enclose constraints into list brackets `[...]`, just need dictionary brackets `{...}`, that you already defined in `c1`:

```
import numpy
import scipy.optimize as opt

def f(x, *args):
    return x[0]

def create_constr(x):
    # x[0]       >= 0.1
    # x[0] - 0.1 >= 0
    return x[0] - 0.1

x0 = numpy.array([1])

c1 = {'type':'ineq', 'fun': create_constr}

res= opt.minimize(f, x0, c1)
print(res)
```

if need several cons - use parenthesis like this e.g.:

```
# inequality means that it is to be non-negative!
# multiplication to -1 reformulates min problem to maximization problem
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  -1*(3*x[0] - 12)},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0] })
```

P.S.: `()` is a *tuple*, `[]` is a *list*, `{}` is a *dict*.

P.P.S. or can make switcher (if need several cons )

```
cons = []
# https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-case-in-python-replacement/
# Switcher is dictionary data type here
def cons_create(flag):
    switcher = {
        0: lambda x: x[0] - 2 * x[1] + i,
        1: lambda x: -x[0] - 2 * x[1] + 6,
        2: lambda x: -x[0] + 2 * x[1] + 2,
    }

    # get() method of dictionary data type returns
    # value of passed argument if it is present
    # in dictionary otherwise second argument will
    # be assigned as default value of passed argument
    return switcher.get(flag, "nothing")


for i in range(3):
    cons.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': cons_create(i)})
```